# Iterative closest point returns incorrect transformation matrix

Tags: matrix, android-ndk, point-cloud-library

I want to create  a point cloud by moving and rotating my depth sensor(the structure sensor). 
What I have so far is the following:

- Create two point clouds that are similar but the second point cloud has shifted a bit.
- Use ICP to get the transformation matrix(I've switched the source and target cloud so I get the inverse).
- Transform the source cloud(the second point cloud I created) with the transformation matrix.
- Add all points that are not already in the total point cloud.

Although I'm moving the sensor slowly new points are added in strange locations so I'm not sure if I'm doing this right. I have a feeling the transformation matrix is wrong because I get values in my translation vector ranging from really low(0,00008) to pretty high (3,00000), these values are both negative and positive.

Some extra information:

- I work on Android with the NDK so I can't use the kinfu example because CUDA isn't supported.
- I use PCL version 1.6.

Any chance someone can help me out?

**Edit, added some code**

*Filtering*

```
pcl::VoxelGrid<pcl::PointXYZ> grid;

grid.setLeafSize (5.01, 5.01, 5.01);
grid.setInputCloud (cloud_in);
grid.filter (*in);

grid.setInputCloud (cloud_out);
grid.filter (*out);
```

*Point adding*

```
pcl::IterativeClosestPoint<pcl::PointXYZ, pcl::PointXYZ> icp;
icp.setInputCloud(out);
icp.setInputTarget(in);
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> Final;
pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ> transformedCloud;
icp.setMaxCorrespondenceDistance(0.1);
icp.setRANSACIterations(5);
icp.setMaximumIterations(20);
icp.setTransformationEpsilon(1e-2);
icp.setEuclideanFitnessEpsilon(1e-5);

icp.align(Final);

if(icp.hasConverged()){
    Eigen::Matrix4f transformationMatrix = icp.getFinalTransformation();

    pcl::transformPointCloud(*cloud_out, *cloud_out, transformationMatrix);
    vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray> conn = vtkSmartPointer<vtkCellArray>::New();

    vtkPoints* oldPoints = totalPolyData->GetPoints();

    for(pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZ>::iterator it = cloud_out->begin(); it != cloud_out->end(); it++){
        if(!find((double) it->x, (double) it->y, (double) it->z)){
            oldPoints->InsertNextPoint((double) it->x, (double) it->y, (double) it->z);
        }
    }

    totalPolyData->SetPoints(oldPoints);
    for (int i = 0; i < oldPoints->GetNumberOfPoints(); i++)
        conn->InsertNextCell(1, &i);
    totalPolyData->SetVerts(conn);
```

Answer (score 0):

You may try to concatenate the two pointclouds entirely (not adding only the non existent points) and check if it's good or not. 
It seems like something wrong is going there and I suspect that it's PCL fault. Can you post the filtering and points adding code you're using ?